# kendoUI MVVM - TreeView with checkbox template

Tags: checkbox, kendo-ui, kendo-treeview, kendo-mvvm, kendo-template

I need to use KendoUI TreeView with MVVM (declarative) binding, and I need to show checkboxes only for some nodes, based on a field in the model.

For this, I want to use [checkbox template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/treeview#configuration-checkboxes-template)

However, whatever I do it seems I cannot make it work

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bzamfir/K6cbc/2/) is the fiddle with the treeview bound through MVVM but without checkbox template

What I want is to use the function **checkTemplate** as checkbox template, by defining the treeview as below

```
<div class="files"
    data-role="treeview" 
    data-text-field="name"
    data-spritecssclass-field="type"
    data-checkboxes="{checkChildren: true, template: checkTemplate }"
    data-bind="source: files"
    data-template= "ktmpl_Files">
</div>
```

However, it doesn't work.
Does anyone has any idea what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template function used for checkboxes is invoked in a context where your "`checkTemplate`" function is not visible. Define it global:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkTemplate(e) {
        return "<input type='checkbox' style='display: " + (e.item.checkable ? "inline" : "none") + "'/>";
    }
</script>
```

Check it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/K6cbc/5/

Comment: Thanks. Actually what made the difference was the parameter passed to template, which I missed.